Boto3 Cognito-IDP script freezing/hanging in lambda
I am trying to create an api that I can use to invite users to my cognito user pool.
However when I call the lambda it hangs...
I have tried increasing the lambda memory to 512Mb and timeout settings to 5mins without success.
This is the function code:
def cognito_register_user(user):
    print("sign up user: ", user["email"])

    try:
        aws_client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name = "eu-west-2",aws_access_key_id="XXXXXX",
                                      aws_secret_access_key="XXXXXX")

        response = aws_client.admin_create_user(
UserPoolId="eu-west-2_XXXXX",
Username=user["email"],
UserAttributes=[{"Name": "email","Value": user["email"]},{ "Name": "email_verified", "Value": "true" },            {
                'Name': 'name',
                'Value': user["name"]
            },
            {
                'Name': 'family_name',
                'Value': user["family_name"]
            },],DesiredDeliveryMediums=['EMAIL'])
        print("response=", response)
        return response
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
    return None

Cloudwatch logs
        2024-04-22T20:00:02.514+01:00   sign up user: XXXX@gmail.com

        2024-04-22T20:05:32.468+01:00   2024-04-22T19:05:32.468Z 85f32ee0-d56b-4fff-a63d-ceffb9c76d1e Task timed out after 330.10 seconds 


What debugging output does it display? Does it print the "sign up user" message? How about the "response=" message?

Apologies I should have added this! The sign up user message is printed but nothing else.

Is the Lambda function connected to a VPC? If so, is there a reason for doing so? If not, disconnect it from the VPC and try again -- this will give it access to the Internet.

ahh I didn't consider it being a network issue! The lambda is connected to a VPC so it can interact with RDS, however I have set up an ENI with a public IP for each subnet. Assuming that would provide connectivity?

I have added an internet gateway to the vpc and thats now brought connectivity. Working now! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

You manually added a Elastic IP to the ENI associated with the Lambda function? That is not recommended because Lambda can recreate the ENIs as necessary, sot they might suddenly disappear one day. The official way to do it is to connect the Lambda function to private subnets and then add a NAT Gateway in a public subnet (charges apply). If it's working for you for the moment, then that's great but be warned that one day it might suddenly stop working due to the ENIs being recreated.

When an AWS Lambda function is not connected to a VPC, it automatically receives Internet access.
If you need to connect a Lambda function to a VPC (eg because it also needs to access an Amazon RDS database in that VPC), then the Lambda function will not automatically receive Internet access. To provide Internet access to the Lambda function, you should:

Connect the Lambda function to private subnets where it will create Elastic Network Interfaces (ENIs)
Add a NAT Gateway to a public subnet (charges apply)

Yes, it is possible to connect the Lambda function to public subnets and manually add Elastic IP addresses to the ENIs to grant the Lambda function access to the Internet. However, the Lambda service might at times create/remove the ENIs, particularly when scaling the Lambda function for high concurrency. In such situations, the ENIs you are using might disappear or new ENIs might be created. This will result in a loss of Internet connectivity. If you are going to use this method, then you will need to monitor the Lambda function for errors and respond when something changes.
